# Multiple Arguments in Jinja templates Flask

Tags: python, templates, flask

I have 4 different types of subscription packages and I need to set template in a way that if one subscription is active than other enrol buttons should be disabled. I have two variables to work with.

```
is_active=True 
subs_type = 'yearly' or 'monthly' or 'quarterly' or 'weekly'
```

On my packages.html page I have 4 packages like:

```
<div>
<h1>Package 1</h1>
<a href="/someurl"><input class"btn" type="submit" value="enroll"></a>
</div>
<div>
<h1>Package 2</h1>
<a href="/someurl"><input class"btn" type="submit" value="enroll"></a>
</div>
<div>
<h1>Package 3</h1>
<a href="/someurl"><input class"btn" type="submit" value="enroll"></a>
</div>
<div>
<h1>Package 4</h1>
<a href="/someurl"><input class"btn" type="submit" value="enroll"></a>
</div>
```

I have few conditions to apply which I couldn't make work together.
1. If user subscribed one of the package then all other enrol button should pop message that he/she already subscribed. 
2. The one that is subscribed should sow cancel button but rest should show enrol button but should work.

Can someone help me to make it work please?

Comment: Does the 4 packages, match the 4 `subs_type`s?

Comment: Only matching variable is is_active==Ture. All the packages are connected with stripe so they can't be matching. pacakge_type is different in all the packages.

Comment: If `subs_type` has no correlation, then how would you know which package the client is subscribed to?

Comment: Each plan is backed by a single view. All the views on submission update a unique value after getting from Stripe. for instance if user subscribes for yearly package db will automatically updated with package_type==yearly. Now problem is I can set it if is active_true then it will show "cancel" button instead of "enrol". But I need to set all other enrol buttons suspended.

Comment: Lets say I need to set something like {% if sub.is_active and sub.pacakge_type!= 'yearly' %} <disable enrol button>{% else %}<show enrol html button something>{% endif %}. I can pass single variable conditions but not multiple.

Comment: Check out my answer. Either I got it right or I don't seem to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Considering what you said in that comments. That `is_active` defines if the client is already subscribed, and `package_type` describes which package the client is subscribed to.

So let's say that package 1 is the yearly package, then:

```
<h1>Package 1</h1>
{% if is_active %}
    {% if package_type == "yearly" %}
    <a href="/someurl"><input class"btn" type="submit" value="cancel"></a>
    {% else %}
    already enrolled to another package
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
<a href="/someurl"><input class"btn" type="submit" value="enroll"></a>
{% endif %}
```

*Assuming you're using jinja and not another templating language.*

Comment: Makes sense but let me apply it to all my packages in HTML and I will tick your answer. Thanks

Comment: If I didn't get it right, then feel free to elaborate on the question. Because that's how I currently understand it.

Comment: One problem so far....if is_active then it should show <html tags for another package subscribed but not this one so this should show subscription active only>. As per my understanding lets say there are 4 types of packages and default one is 'NOPACKAGE' if no subscription only than it should show subscription option.

Comment: If any other package is subscribed then <input button disabled>. So can we do something like {% if not package_type=='yearly' and is_active==True %}<enrol disabled>{% else %} <enrol enabled>{% endif %}. I can't make multiple variables work so I thought there should be a way out.

Comment: For the next package if you change it to `package_type == "monthly"` then that package should say "already enrolled to another package" if say the client is subscribed to the yearly package. Isn't this the goal? Because I'm not sure I completely follow.